# LESS import not working

Tags: css, import, less, c-preprocessor

I am having trouble using @import. I have a style.less file that looks like this so far:

```
/*
* Screen-Cuts.Com Styles
* 
*/


/* Mixins
======================================== */

@import "grid.less";

/* Main Page Styles 
======================================== */

body {
}

header {
    h1 {
        font-family: 'Exo', san-serif;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 2.25em
    }
    nav[role="navigation"] {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.25em;

        ul {
            list-style: none;

            li {
                float: left;
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

When I compile the less code, however, the @import does not seem to work, and I am not getting any compile errors. Here is the output:

```
/*
 * Screen-Cuts.Com Styles
 * 
 */
/* Variables
======================================== */
/* Mixins
======================================== */
/* Main Page Styles 
======================================== */
header h1 {
  font-family: 'Exo', san-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 2.25em;
}
header nav[role="navigation"] {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
header nav[role="navigation"] ul {
  list-style: none;
}
header nav[role="navigation"] ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

Furthermore, when I attempt to use the mixins defined in grid.less, I get a compile time error saying that the mixin is not defined. Can anyone help me out here? I'm sure I'm making a dumb error, but I've looked around quite a bit and have been unable to find a clue.

Comment: @Ethan--you should note your solution as an answer and then "accept" it.

Comment: @Ethan--Well, you did half that. You put your solution as an answer, but you did not click the check mark to the left of it to "accept" it.

Comment: @Ethan--oh yes. Thanks for following through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem here. There was a compile error in the grid.less file. Once I fixed that error the file was imported.

Comment: I ran into this too was the importing file wouldn't compile. Less just silently didn't import it and I was getting an error that mixings weren't defined. Is there an option to fail on import failures and is it not the default?